# Imported library works on dev but not after build

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, node-modules, vite

I've recently converted an existing project from webpack to Vite and I'm having some problems with the following lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@3e/sqa-common.

Everything runs fine on development but after i run the build process the lib returns an empty object.

The build process was working fine on webpack.

I think this is clear enough but i'm glad to provide more details if necessary.

**Reproduction**

https://github.com/pedrozok/vite-demo

**Steps to reproduce**

run `npm install && npm run dev` -> everything is working fine, the content of the library is being printed on the page with json.stringify

run `npm run build && npm run preview` -> the error occurs, the library returns an empty object.

**Dependencies**

- node: 16.19.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.1/bin/node
- npm: 8.19.3 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.1/bin/npm
- vite: ^4.3.2
- @3e/sqa-common: ^6.13.0-1hotfix5